# Squeeze text effect

Tags: text-object

Any idea on how it has been done? I've tried with soft body but the result isn't greaT, and if I modify the objects with cloth simulation and I give them some pressure adding collision to the box that contains them, nothing good happens. Thanks a lot for the help! [image]

Comment: cloth + pressure is the solution. What did you try about that? can you show us your tests?

Comment: Hey I'll show you it when I get home! The result was really poor because the objects weren't really squeezed into the box, as if collision didn't work properly. Thanks a lot! Ciao!

Comment: No inflated _letter-shaped_ letters would deform to this extent in real life. I think you would have to give them a helping hand. My guess is: model them to be distorted and _almost_ space-filling, and let a cloth simulation finish the illusion.

Comment: Hey Robin, I'm sure the artist finished the work sculpting some parts, but I don't know what was the first step.

Comment: Cloth sculpt tool might get you there. And then refine with the simulation like @Robin Betts says.

Comment: Sculpted extruded text is another option.

Comment: Update: I tried cloth simulation with lots of pressure and 0 gravity and then lattice modifier: not bad at all.